# prove by definition that $\log^k(n) = o(n^\epsilon)$

Tags: calculus, analysis, algorithms

So I have tried to prove by definition that $\log^k(n) = o(n^\epsilon)$ $for$ k>1 and $\epsilon>0$
But unfortunately, couldn't find the solution.
I have tried to use log rules and exponent  rules...
Also, I know that $n^\epsilon=o(k^n)$ and that  $f(x)=o(g(x))$ if and only if 
 $g(x)=\omega(f(x))$

As well, I know this question has been asked already.But all the solutions are based on limits.And **I want to prove by definition only, without limits**.

Would be glad to hear some advises.

Answer (score 1):

[Cauchy-Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) says that
$$
\begin{align}
\log(n)
&=\int_1^n\frac1x\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&\le\left(\int_1^n1\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_1^nx^{-2}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/2}\\[6pt]
&\le n^{1/2}1^{1/2}\\[12pt]
&=n^{1/2}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac{\log(n)}n\le n^{-1/2}
$$
Substituting $n\mapsto n^{\epsilon/k}$, then raising to the $k^\text{th}$ power gives
$$
\left(\frac\epsilon{k}\frac{\log(n)}{n^{\epsilon/k}}\right)^k\le\left(n^{-\large\frac\epsilon{2k}}\right)^k
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
\frac{\log(n)^k}{n^\epsilon}\le\left(\frac{k}\epsilon\right)^kn^{-\epsilon/2}
$$
which means that
$$
\log(n)^k=o\!\left(n^\epsilon\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

This is what I thought of.Please, let me know what you think

Let’s assume by contradiction that $f(n)≠o(g(n))$ 
We know that $f(n)=o(g(n))⟺g(n)=ω(f(n))$ 
It means that $f(n)≠o(g(n))⟺g(n)≠ω(f(n))$
So $g(n)≠ω(f(n))⟹∃c_1>0$   s.t $ 0≤c_1 g(n)<f(n)  ,∀n>0$ 
 $⟹0≤c_1 n^ε<((lg⁡(n)(^b )   ,∀n>0   (*)$  
Also $g(n)=o(b^n )$ because $b>1,ε>0$ 
So, by definition of $b^n=ω(g(n))$ 
$∀c>0 ∃n_0>0$ s.t $0≤cb^n<g(n)  ,∀n≥n_o⟹0≤cb^n<n^ϵ  ,   ∀n≥n_0  (**)$ 
From (*) 
We know that: $lg⁡(n)≤n $  as well, $lg⁡(n)^b≤n^b≤b^n$
Hence, for $c_1$     $0≤ c_1 n^ε<(lg⁡(n)^b )≤n^b≤b^n,∀n>0$
But this is in contradiction to the (**), because $ cn^ϵ<b^n$  for all $c>0$