# Prove that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty {\ln(n)\over n^{1+c}}$ converges for $c > 0$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am studying series in my calculus class, and the teacher asked us to prove that the series:
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty {\ln(n)\over n^{1+c}}$$
converges when $c > 0$.

I tried using the direct comparison test with ${\ln(n)\over n^{1+c}}$ as the $a_n$ and  ${n\over n^{1+c}}$ as the $b_n$, since I know the latter is larger than the former, and because I thought that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty b_n$ converges, but since ${n\over n^{1+c}} = {1\over n^c}$, $\sum_{i=1}^\infty b_n$ is actually a p-series with $p = c$. As such, since I only know that $c > 0$, I can't guarantee that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty b_n$ converges.

I thought about using the integral convergence test, but is there another way?

Comment: Note that for any $c > 0,$ $\log(n)/n^{c/2} \to 0$ as $n \nearrow \infty$. So, there exists some $n_0(c)$ such that for $n > n_0(c), \log(n) < n^{c/2}$. This means that there exists some number $K(c)$ such that for every $n$, $\log(n) \le K(c) n^{c/2},$ at which point you can use the comparison test.

Comment: I don't really understand two things: why ${log(n)/n^{c/2}}$ tends to $0$, and how using this number $K(c)$ changes the original problem. It will still be a p-series with an $p$ I can't determine, right?

Comment: You can prove it, for instance by L'Hospital's method. As for the use, you then have the upper bound $\sum \log(n)/n^{1+c} \le K(c) \sum 1/ n^{1 + c/2}$ - which is a $p$-series with $p = 1 + c/2 > 1,$ so its finite.

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand. But why bother with the $K(c)$? Wouldn't just $n^{c/2}$ suffice? Also, this might be stupid but why do you put $(c)$ after the $K$? Is it because the K is dependent on the c?

Comment: Yeah, equally fine. You just need it because otherwise the upper bound is $\sum_{ n \le n_0(c)} \log(n)/n^{1 + c} + \sum_{n > n_0(c)} 1/n^{1+c/2}$, and I found the earlier thing easier to write :P. And yes, the $(c)$ just indicates that these numbers depend on $c$.

Comment: I see, thank you very much for the help! My current calculus class does not go very deep into most subjects, so I was a bit lost, but now I understand :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that for every $\alpha>0$, there is a constant $C_{\alpha}>0$ such that $\ln n\leq C_{\alpha}n^{\alpha}$ for all $n\geq 1$.

One may pick $\alpha>0$ so small such that $1+c-\alpha>1$, then the sum $\displaystyle\sum\dfrac{1}{n^{1+c-\alpha}}$ still converges.

Comment: I don't really understand. Could you elaborate on that? My knowledge of calculus is really hit-or-miss, my apologies.

Comment: In some sense @stochasticboy321 has explained the reasoning.

Comment: An equivalent approach is using the limit-comparison test with $\sum_n\frac1{n^{1+c/2}}$.

Answer (score 1):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3430134), it is shown that for any $k$ and $\epsilon$, $\log(n)^k=o\!\left(n^\epsilon\right)$; that is,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n)^k}{n^\epsilon}=0\tag1
$$
For this question, we only need $k=1$ and $\epsilon=\frac c2$. $(1)$ implies that there is an $M_c$ so that
$$
\frac{\log(n)}{n^{c/2}}\le M_c\tag2
$$
Thus,
$$
\frac{\log(n)}{n^{1+c}}\le\frac{M_c}{n^{1+c/2}}\tag3
$$
By the $p$-test and comparison, $(3)$ proves the convergence of
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\log(n)}{n^{1+c}}
$$